# Hiding inside group columns from other columns that don't have values

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm working on a report. How do I get columns from the outside that are displaying dates to be next to a column inside the matrix that is displaying values.

For example it is setup like this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |         [Type]         |   LicDt   |    MedDt   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   |  [HiredDt]  | [TermDt] |  SUM([Count_of_Type])  |  [LicDt]  |   [MedDt]  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And looks like this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |   Lic   |   Med   |   App   |     LicDt   |    MedDt   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  1/31/12    | 1/31/14  |    1    |    1    |    12   |    6/1/15   |   9/1/14   |
2    |  2/19/12    | 9/18/14  |    1    |    1    |    12   |    3/2/15   |   9/1/14   |
```

But when I use inside grouping to match up the date next to the associated document type I get:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |   Lic   |           |        |   Med   |        |             |   App   |        |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  1/31/12    | 1/31/14  |    1    |   6/1/15  |        |    1    |        |  9/1/2014   |    12   |        |         |
2    |  2/19/12    | 9/18/14  |    1    |   3/2/15  |        |    1    |        |  9/1/2014   |    12   |        |         |
```

What I'm trying to get this:

```
     |   HiredDt   |  TermDt  |   Lic   |   LicDt   |   Med   |   MedDt   |    App   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    |  1/31/12    | 1/31/14  |    1    |   6/1/15  |    1    |  9/1/14   |     12   |
2    |  2/19/12    | 9/18/14  |    1    |   3/2/15  |    1    |  9/1/14   |     12   |
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would right-click on the cell you have labelled `SUM([Count_of_Type])` and choose Insert Column - Inside Group - Right.

In that new cell I would set the expression to: `= Max ( [LicDt] )`